# Using Vim, how can I make CSS rules into one liners?

Tags: css, regex, vim, replace

I would like to come up with a Vim substitution command to turn multi-line CSS rules, like this one:

```
#main {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 10px auto;
}
```

into compacted single-line rules, like so:

```
#main {padding:0;margin:10px auto;}
```

I have a ton of CSS rules that are taking up too many lines, and I cannot figure out the `:%s/` commands to use.

Comment: +1 thanks for the question. learned a lot from rampion's answer!

Comment: Please, take a look at the command I propose in my answer [below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10797846/254635).  Comments to the answer are welcome!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here's a one-liner:

```
:%s/{\_.\{-}}/\=substitute(submatch(0), '\n', '', 'g')/
```

`\_.` matches any character, including a newline, and `\{-}` is the non-greedy version of `*`, so `{\_.\{-}}` matches everything between a matching pair of curly braces, inclusive.

The `\=` allows you to substitute the result of a vim expression, which we here use to strip out all the newlines `'\n'` from the matched text (in `submatch(0)`) using the `substitute()` function.

The inverse (converting the one-line version to multi-line) can also be done as a one liner:

```
:%s/{\_.\{-}}/\=substitute(submatch(0), '[{;]', '\0\r', 'g')/
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is awesome.

Conversely, how would you convert a bunch of one-line CSS rules into the multiple line format?

Comment: You don't need to play with \= to do the reverse operation. A simple :%s/[{;]/&\r/g | gg=G is more than enough.

Answer (score 11):

If you are at the beginning or end of the rule, `V%J` will join it into a single line:

- Go to the opening (or closing) brace
- Hit `V` to enter visual mode
- Hit `%` to match the other brace, selecting the whole rule
- Hit `J` to join the lines

Comment: this is not the *vi* way, it's the *vim* way

Comment: Thanks, this is really cool. Now I understand visual mode a little better.

Comment: Well, soulmerge, first I wanted to say `vim` way, but then it *is* a `vi` way even if this particular command is not compatible with plain `vi` (I'm not even sure it isn't).

Comment: It's not compatible with plain `vi`. But the question is tagged as `vim` and I guess the vast majority of people normally use `vim`, so the answer should be useful.

Comment: This only fixes one block at a time, though. Using :%s would fix the entire file.

Comment: sth, true, I failed to find plain vi anywhere around to check what exactly won't work there. ;-)

Comment: vi doesn't have Vim's visual mode (as noted in `:help visual`).  What vi called visual mode was just another name for normal mode.

Answer (score 4):

Try something like this:

```
:%s/{\n/{/g
:%s/;\n/;/g
:%s/{\s+/{/g
:%s/;\s+/;/g
```

This removes the newlines after opening braces and semicolons ('{' and ';') and then removes the extra whitespace between the concatenated lines.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to change the file, go for [rampion's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1422866/using-vi-how-can-i-make-css-rules-into-one-liners/1423066#1423066).

If you don't want (or can't) change the file, you can play with a custom folding as it permits to choose what and how to display the folded text. For instance:

```
" {rtp}/fold/css-fold.vim
" [-- local settings --]               {{{1
setlocal foldexpr=CssFold(v:lnum)
setlocal foldtext=CssFoldText()

let b:width1 = 20
let b:width2 = 15

nnoremap <buffer> + :let b:width2+=1<cr><c-l>
nnoremap <buffer> - :let b:width2-=1<cr><c-l>

" [-- global definitions --]           {{{1
if exists('*CssFold')
  setlocal foldmethod=expr
  " finish
endif

function! CssFold(lnum)
  let cline = getline(a:lnum)
  if     cline =~ '{\s*$'
      return 'a1'
  elseif cline =~ '}\s*$'
      return 's1'
  else
      return '='
  endif
endfunction

function! s:Complete(txt, width)
  let length = strlen(a:txt)
  if length > a:width
      return a:txt
  endif
  return a:txt . repeat(' ', a:width - length)
endfunction

function! CssFoldText()
  let lnum = v:foldstart
  let txt = s:Complete(getline(lnum), b:width1)
  let lnum += 1
  while lnum < v:foldend
      let add = s:Complete(substitute(getline(lnum), '^\s*\(\S\+\)\s*:\s*\(.\{-}\)\s*;\s*$', '\1: \2;', ''), b:width2)
      if add !~ '^\s*$'
          let txt .= ' ' . add
      endif

      let lnum += 1
  endwhile
  return txt. '}'
endfunction
```

*I leave the sorting of the fields as exercise. Hint: get all the lines between v:foldstart+1 and v:voldend in a List, sort the list, build the string, and that's all.*

Answer (score 3):

I won’t answer the question directly, but instead I suggest you to reconsider your needs. I think that your “bad” example is in fact the better one. It is more readable, easier to modify and reason about. Good indentation is very important not only when it comes to programming languages, but also in CSS and HTML.

You mention that CSS rules are “taking up too many lines”. If you are worried about file size, you should consider using CSS and JS minifiers like [YUI Compressor](https://github.com/yui/yuicompressor) instead of making the code less readable.

Comment: this is a religious debate. some devs prefer css rules in one liners because it's quicker/easier to scan for and find selectors.  others prefer multi-line because it's easier to se what has changed when you diff.

Answer (score 1):

A convenient way of doing this transformation is to run the following
short command:

```
:g/{/,/}/j
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to the first line of the file, and use the command `gqG` to run the whole file through the formatter. Assuming runs of nonempty lines should be collapsed in the whole file.