# Custom folding for CSS in Vim

Tags: css, vim, folding

I came upon this [custom folding for CSS in Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1422866/using-vi-how-can-i-make-css-rules-into-one-liners/1423394#1423394) and inspired by it I was
trying to make my own with slightly different result in mind. I had to give up
as I couldn't make search patterns work in folding function. No surprise to me
as I'm rather a Vim beginner :)

Any help to achieve the following will be much appreciated.

- I use empty line(s) for separation for readability. Plus it enables
  navigation with Vim's <kbd>}</kbd> and
  <kbd>{</kbd>.
- I put every selector on its own line.
- I group declarations into sections, which often are nested.

The sample input is:

```
/* # Globals
===================================== */

...

/* ## Lists
------------------------------------- */

ol,
ul {
  margin-top: 1.6154em; /*21px*/
  /* Some other comment */
  list-style-position: outside;
}

dl,
dl > some .very.long + selector:not-fitting[on=screen] {
  ...
```

I want to:

1. Fold sections based on their level.

   The section level is indicated by a number of `#`, thus in the above
   example "Globals" should have fold level 1 and "Lists" -- 2. There can be a
   third level too.

   The fold text for a section should not contain any `#`.
2. Start a fold for declaration at the first selector.
3. End a fold at the last empty line following the declaration's closing brace
   `}`.
4. Display *all* selectors in the fold text.

   In case they don't fit in the window, display those that do and a count of
   not displayed ones.

I'll illustrate it using the sample provided above.

When using `:set foldmethod=marker` and `:set foldmarker={,}` the resulting fold is:

```
ol,
+----  5 lines: ul -------------------------

dl,
+----  x lines: dl > some .very.long ...----
```

And I'd like it to be (notice there's no empty line between folds):

```
+---- ol, ul -------------------------------
+---- dl ---------------------------[1]-----
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this [folding plugin for CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1422866/using-vi-how-can-i-make-css-rules-into-one-liners/1423394#1423394) I wrote for SO. It should be easy to improve it to your needs. You will have to test the lines around the current line -- it may be more efficient to detect all curly brackets, and cache them, in order to known when to look for continuing lines.