# How to make all the attributions in the css selector into one line with vim?

Tags: css, vim

Here is my css part of css file.

```
body{
    width:1100px;
    height:800px;
}
div.main{
    margin:20px auto 0 auto;
    background-color:#f7f7f7;
}
```

I want to rewrite it as below.

```
body{width:1100px;height:800px;}
div.main{margin:20px auto 0 auto;background-color:#f7f7f7;}
```

All attritutions and values rewritten as only one line,is there a smarty vim command to do the job?

Comment: Use a minifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be

```
g/{/,/}/j
```

which breaks down as

```
g        start a global command
{        search for {
,/}/    for each match, set a range up until the }
j       join the range
```

Note that this might be to naïve as-is. This doesn't take into account nested brackets. You might first want to set a visual range to the textblock you like to change.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `J` or `gJ` (alternative that doesn't add spaces) commands. They can be run in visual mode to join all selected lines, or take a count.

Alternatively, the [splitjoin.vim](https://github.com/AndrewRadev/splitjoin.vim) plugin provides specific support for css rules as you are asking. With the cursor over the first line of the css block, type `gJ` to join the whole block into a single line.

Either way, you may want/need to run a replace to remove leading spaces before joining - `:s/^\s\+//` before joining the lines.

EDIT: I guess a 'smarty' way to do this, and without using plugins, would be the following macro: `vf}:s/^\s\+/^MgvgJ` (the `^M` means pressing the enter key - you may have to enter the macro manually to get this). Use it by putting the cursor at the beginning of the line at the top of the css rule you want to rewrite.

Answer (score 1):

As @romainl said, you should use a minifier. However I am going to assume what you really want is a way to glance at your css rules quickly. If that is the case then I suggest you look into folding. @Luc Hermitte gave a [great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1423394/438329) on this subject on the post: [Using vi, how can I make CSS rules into one liners?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1422866/438329)

Below is a variant of @Luc Hermitte answer. Put the following in `~/.vim/ftplugin/css_fold.vim`:

```
let b:width = 25

" Use the following mappings to adjust the foldtext "columns"
nnoremap <silent> <buffer> >s :<c-u>let b:width+=v:count1<cr><c-l>
nnoremap <silent> <buffer> <s :<c-u>let b:width-=v:count1<cr><c-l>

if !exists('*s:CssFoldText')
  function! s:CssFoldText()
    let line = printf("% *s {", -1*b:width, substitute(getline(v:foldstart), "{\s*$", "", ""))
    let nnum = nextnonblank(v:foldstart + 1)
    let lst = []
    while nnum <= v:foldend
      let line = line . " " . substitute(getline(nnum), "^\s*", "", "")
      let nnum += 1
    endwhile
    return line
  endfunction 

  map <SID>xx <SID>xx
  let s:sid = substitute(maparg("<SID>xx"),'xx$','', '')
  unmap <SID>xx

endif

exe "setlocal foldtext=" . s:sid . "CssFoldText()"
setlocal foldmethod=syntax
```

Now you can use folding commands like `zM` to close all folds, `zR` to open all folds, and `za` to toggle the current fold. [Vimcasts](http://vimcasts.org/) has a nice screencast on this topic, [How to fold](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/how-to-fold/).

For more information see:

```
:h folds
:h 'foldtext'
:h 'foldmethod'
:h za
:h zR
:h zM
```